# Козлы и козлЫ

Tags: этимология, омонимы

Почему гимнастический снаряд называет козел (а есть еще конь), я могу понять - все-таки это нечто невысокое и четвероногое. А вот есть ли связь между словом "козел" у слова "кОзлы" - то есть, либо некая подставка под что-то, например, в плотницком деле, либо сиденье для кучера.
И, опять же, если в случае подставки я еще могу усмотреть какое-то сходство с четвероногим животным, но кучерское сиденье уж совсем никакого сходства не имеет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Козлы бывают разные.

http://mediasubs.ru/group/uploads/vs/vsyo-o-remonte-svoimi-rukami-dostupno-dazhe-rebyonku/image2/hhMzgtNTk.jpg

http://static01.rupor.sampo.ru/remote/f40f3dd9227f30d6a8dcc02da71649fc.jpg

http://mainstro.ru/netcat_files/userfiles/2013/April%202013/stat%201/71.jpg

http://www.charliesdirect.co.uk/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/900x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/s/t/stihl-metal-saw-horse-1_5.jpg

http://www.orbita-tis.ru/imgcatalog/pic131067.jpg

Если что непонятно, спрашивайте.